# How can I replace a character on specific strings on a file?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, notepad++

I have to replace the character '**.**' for an '**_**' but only on specific regions of the file (the function names), I have a file like this:

```
\name{function.name.something}

\usage{function.name.something(parameter.something, parameter2.something)}
```

I was thinking of using notepad++ or sed, and only replace on the captured groups, for example the first line would be:

`\\name\{(.+)\}`
and replace the with `\\name\{\1\}`

but with the **group 1** (**\1**) having the dots replaced by underscores

I appreciate any help and thank you

Comment: What if you have `\usage{function1.name(function2.name(param1.var), param2.var)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\\\name{[^}]+}|\\S+' '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1)} 1' file
\name{function_name_something}

\usage{function.name.something(parameter.something, parameter2.something)}
```

`FPAT='\\\\name{[^}]+}|\\S+'` will parse each field using given regex here which is `\name{...}` OR some non-space string (default awk field).

**More testing:**

```
cat file
\name{function.name.something} abc.foo.bar    
\usage{function.name.something(parameter.something, parameter2.something)}

awk -v FPAT='\\\\name{[^}]+}|\\S+' '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1)} 1' f
\name{function_name_something} abc.foo.bar    
\usage{function_name_something(parameter_something, parameter2.something)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked very well. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
< file.txt perl -pe '
                    ($n, $f) = /(\\name|\\usage)\{(.*?[}(])/
                    and s/\Q$n\E\{\Q$f\E/"$n\{" . ($f=~s=\.=_=gr)/e'
```

Needs Perl 5.14+, otherwise you have to write

```
($n, $f) = /(\\name|\\usage)\{(.*?[}(])/
and s/\Q$n\E\{\Q$f\E/"$n\{" . do { ($ff = $f) =~ s=\.=_=g; $ff }/e
```